# Is it possible to launch a local Vue CLI 3 web application from a ASP.NET Core 3 console application?

Tags: c#, vue.js, asp.net-core

Lets say I have a ASP.NET Core 3 console application, working as a API using endpoints and websockets to send data, and a Vue CLI 3 application that reads from the API/websockets. Would it be possible to run the web app on a localhost server from the console app when it is launched?

I understand this question is more conceptual and I can not provide any code. We're talking about a standard Vue CLI 3 app as well as a template ASP.NET Core 3 API. I have tried to research this but it has been challenging finding concrete answers.

Comment: I've never worked with Vuew CLI before, but it should be possible. In C# you have the class [Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netcore-3.0) which allows you to execute commands on a command prompt

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I found the most promising solution to be to serve them as static files in the ASP.NET solution, as they should be running on the same web-server as the original project.